# getting all images from a specific fb pages with python

Tags: python, facebook

```
import csv
import ntpath
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

filter="blablabla"
for post in get_posts('FB_page',pages=5, cookies= "documents\cookies.json") :
    if (filter in post['text']):
        for images in post['image']:
            with open("images7.csv", "a", newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(images)
```

this code gets me only one image per post ?!